# Build error with rn-fetch-blob on windows

Tags: react-native, rn-fetch-blob

Hi I am getting an error Unable to resolve module 'rn-fetch-blob' while bundling my app with native template 6.1.5

This is the error

```
[Error] error Unable to resolve module rn-fetch-blob from C:\deployment\native\widgets\node_modules\rn-fetch-blob\index.js: rn-fetch-blob could not be found within the project.
```

any solution to solve this problem?
Any help appreciated

Comment: could yoe please clear the build folder and try again?

Comment: Hi, @Lukas I did,  I also reset-cache but the issue still persists.

Comment: Does building for emulator works fine?

Comment: @Lukas No, that's where I am getting the error. I am able to run npm run build but when I am bundling my project for emulator the build fails